# Preventing race conditions for message processing

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a J2EE application that receives messages (events) via a web service.  The messages are of varying types (requiring different processing depending on type) and sent in a specific sequence.  It have identified a problem where some message types take longer to process than others.  The result is that a message received second in a sequence may be processed before the first in the sequence.  I have tried to address this problem by placing a synchronized block around the method that processes the messages.  This seems to work, but I am not confident that this is the "correct" approach?  Is there perhaps an alternative that may be more appropriate or is this "acceptable"?  I have included a small snippit of code to try to explain more clearly.  .... Any advice / guidance appreciated.

```
public class EventServiceImpl implements EventService {
  public String submit (String msg) {

    if (msg == null)
        return ("NAK");

            EventQueue.getInstance().submit(msg);

    return "ACK";
  }
}


public class EventQueue {
    private static EventQueue instance = null;
    private static int QUEUE_LENGTH = 10000;
    protected boolean done = false;
    BlockingQueue<String> myQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(QUEUE_LENGTH);

protected EventQueue() {
    new Thread(new Consumer(myQueue)).start();
}

public static EventQueue getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new EventQueue();
      }
      return instance;
}

public void submit(String event) {
    try {
        myQueue.put(event);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {
    protected BlockingQueue<String> queue;

    Consumer(BlockingQueue<String> theQueue) { this.queue = theQueue; }

    public void run() {
      try {
        while (true) {
          Object obj = queue.take();
          process(obj);
          if (done) {
            return;
          }
        }
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      }
    }

    void process(Object obj) {
        Event event = new Event( (String) obj);
        EventHandler handler = EventHandlerFactory.getInstance(event);
        handler.execute();
    }
}

// Close queue gracefully
public void close() {
    this.done = true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what is the framework (EJB(MDB)/JMS)  you are working with. Generally using synchronization inside a *Managed Environment* like that of EJB/JMS should be avoided(its not a good practice). One way to get around is

- the client should wait for the acknowledgement from the server before it sends the next message.
- this way you client itself will control the sequence of events.

Please note this won't work if there are multiple client submitting the messages.

EDIT:

You have a situation wherein the client of the web service sends message in sequence without taking into account the message processing time. It simply dumps the message one after another. This is a good case for [Queue ( First In First Out )](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29) based solution. I suggest following two ways to accomplish this

1. Use [JMS](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Ecommerce/jms/) . This will have an additional overhead of adding a [JMS providers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service#Provider_implementations) and writing some plumbing code.
2. Use some multitheading pattern like [Producer-Consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) wherein your web service handler will be dumping the incoming message in a Queue and a **single threaded** consumer will consume one message at a time. See [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Threads/ProducerconsumerforJ2SE15usingconcurrent.htm) using java.util.concurrent package.
3. Use database. Dump the incoming messages into a database. Use a different scheduler based program to scan the datbase (based on sequence number) and process the messages accordingly.

   First and third  solution is very standard for these type of problems. The second approach would be quick and won't need any additional libraries in your code.

Comment: In this case I don't have any access/control over the system sending the messages - although each message does include a sequence number.  I have used cxf to build the web service that receives the messages.

Comment: and you have multiple client sending in their own sequence of message ?

Comment: There is a single client for the service.  Actually, the idea of a FIFO had crossed my mind, although I was not really sure how to implement it (I will read through the references) - I think that JMS (for me) may be adding too much complexity.

Comment: I have modified the code example above to include a calss based very closly on the example that you referenced of the using java.util.concurrent package.  It certainly seems to fuction correctly.

Comment: Looks good :). Since you have declared the queue without any capacity, it will have `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as capacity this would avoid any blocking on submitting the object for processing (I am sure your number of objects to be processed are far lesser than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`)

Comment: It might be best to have some sort of limit.  I modified the code to include the change.  I have just loaded the app into a live system and so far it is performing well.  Thank you for the guidance - it is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If the events are to be processed in a specific sequence, then why not try adding "eventID" and 'orderID' fields to the messages?  This way your EventServiceImpl class can sort, order and then execute in the proper order (regardless of the order they are created and/or delivered to the handler).

Synchronizing the `handler.execute()` block will not get the desired results, I expect.  All the `synchronized` keyword does is prevent multiple threads from executing that block at the same time.  It does nothing in the realm of properly ordering which thread goes next.

If the `synchronized` block does seem to make things work, then I assert you are getting very lucky in that the messages are being created, delivered and then acted upon in the proper order.  In a multithread environment, this is not assured!  I'd take steps to assure you are controlling this, rather than relying on good fortune.

Example:

1. Messages are created in the order 'client01-A', 'client01-C',
   'client01-B', 'client01-D'
2. Messages arrive at the handler in the order 'client01-D',
   'client01-B', 'client01-A', 'client01-C'
3. EventHandler can distinquish messages from one client to another and starts to cache 'client01' 's messages.
4. EventHandler recv's 'client01-A' message and knows it can process this and does so.
5. EventHandler looks in cache for message 'client01-B', finds it and processes it.
6. EventHandler cannot find 'client01-C' because it hasn't arrived yet.
7. EventHandler recv's 'client01-C' and processes it.
8. EventHandler looks in cache for 'client01-D' finds it, processes it, and considers the 'client01' interaction complete.

Something along these lines would assure proper processing and would promote good use of multiple threads.

Comment: Thank you for your comments.  I don't have control over the sending system, however it is designed to send messages in the correct sequence (although I suspect that it cannot be guaranteed).  One of the issues is that in my code the handler is invoked each time a message is received.  Say messages are received every 2ms, and the first message (only) takes 30 ms to process.  Then a second instance of the handler will process message 2 whilst the first message is being processed (corrupting the data).  In the method you describe would the handler have to be a singleton to process sequentially?

Comment: A singleton would probably be the cleanest way to implement a datastructure that multiple threads can access easily, yes.
Question:  Since you have no control over the creation of the messages, is each message of a different type or are there >1 of the same type in each 'set' of messages?

Comment: There are multiple types of messages.  The factory returns a handler for the type of message received.  The message is then processed by calling the execute method on the handler - esentially the command pattern.  In my example above the first message might contain data that the second message operates on - so the first message type handler persists the data - the second manipulates it.

Comment: That is where my idea of the synchronized block came from - trying to ensure that one execute method completed before the next commenced. But as you pointed out there is nothing here which manages the "sequence" of the messages.

Comment: So is there any way to 'sequence' the messages based on the message type?

Comment: Yes, although is is a little more complex in that multiple sequences can be interlaced.  To provide more detail the messages contain medical information.  Each message relates to a specific patient.  Sequences of messages for a specific patient manipulate data relating to that patient - and multiple messages sequences (patient data sets) are interlaced.  Messages include an identifier indicating a sequence position.

Comment: Is there anyway to extract some sort of Patient ID or other unique Identifier?

Comment: Yes, each message has a series of identifiers including a patient  ID as well as a message ID.